# How to add jQuery code after js snippet is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble adding click function to the button which is loaded with JS snippet, because when I try doing the function like this on document.ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
    $(".esis__heading").on('click', function(event){
      console.log('123123');
})});
```

it fails because the element is not loaded and visible yet.

I was thinking maybe timeout is a solution but I started to think it's not a perfect solution.
If someone has any advice on how to deal with this it would help a lot.
This is the link to a page which has a snippet that loads after some time https://samsung.plutonium.rs/samsung/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You solve this by delegating the click to a parent element, at worst this can be the `document` itself

```
$(document).ready(function( $ ){   
    $(document).on('click', ".esis__heading", function(event){
      console.log('123123');
    });
});
```

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић "not working" is not really much for me to go on to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer the load of the script using the defer attribute

[Defer documentation (w3schools.com)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

The only downside is that it works only on external scripts (script tags with src attribute).

Comment: Script we use already has empty async attribute like this async=""